# What is counterportation for the layman?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, quantum-teleportation

The word counterportation has been appearing in my sphere of the internet somewhat frequently and I don’t think I understand what it is.

See here:

https://phys.org/news/2023-03-counterportation-quantum-breakthrough-paves-world-first.html

https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06586

Counterfactual Computation and Teleportation are both intuitive concepts. The first being getting the output of a computation as if you had turned a computer on but without necessarily turning it on.

The latter being an instantaneous transfer of matter (or transfer <= light speed)

I can’t seem to understand what counterportation means however. The paper I linked describes it as:

> “… [the] counterfactual disembodied transport of an unknown qubit“

So does that mean it’s a device which could transport a qubit but doesn’t actually get activated yet the entire system behaves as if the qubit could been transported.

What is the significance of this result exactly? How overhyped is the description of “synthetic wormhole”?

Answer (score 4):

The discussion of "wormholes" in the paper is nonsense. Everything in this experiment is correctly modeled by undergraduate quantum mechanics. It has nothing to do with quantum gravity.

The substantive part of the paper seems to be a variant of the Vaidman bomb tester. Borrowing a description from another answer of mine:

> The general setup is that you have a quantum circuit that computes the answer to some decision problem, and is equivalent to a CNOT gate if the answer is yes, or a no-op if the answer is no. You initialize the control bit to $|0\rangle$ and then repeatedly rotate it one $n$th of the way toward $|1\rangle$, do the decision-problem computation, then measure the output bit to see if it's flipped.
>
> If the circuit is equivalent to a no-op, then the control and output bits are uncorrelated, so measuring the output bit does nothing, and after $n$ rotations the control bit is guaranteed to be $|1\rangle$.
>
> If the circuit is equivalent to a CNOT, then measuring an unflipped output bit means the control bit was $0$ (you don't know that, but the universe does), so the system collapses back to its initial state, and after $n$ repetitions where you measure an unflipped output, the control bit's final measured value is its initial value of $0$, meaning the answer must be yes, but the computation never happened.
>
> If you ever measure a flipped output bit, then the computation did happen (the "bomb explodes" case), but the chance of that can be made arbitrarily small by choosing $n$ large.

Here, the computation involves Alice sending a qubit to Bob, who does something to it and sends it back to Alice. You can make the probability that this happens be arbitrarily close to (but not exactly) 0, while still getting the result of the transport of a qubit from Bob to Alice.

I want to make a couple of points about this. First, the standard quantum teleportation protocol has the potential to be practically useful, because it doesn't require a quantum channel to exist at the time the qubit is sent. A quantum channel is needed, but it can exist only at an earlier time, and it can be unidirectional in the opposite direction, which gives you some flexibility. In contrast, the protocol in this paper requires a bidirectional quantum channel to exist when the message is sent, and it requires waiting for multiple round trips. Even if it is technically unused, it has to be there and in good working order and you have to wait for the round trips that don't actually happen. In contrast, just sending the qubit from Bob to Alice requires only a unidirectional channel and a single one-way wait. So there is no chance that this protocol could be useful. I argued in [that other answer](/a/733940) that the bomb-testing protocol can never save on resources, because any savings amounts to an information leak that prevents it from working.

Second, "counterfactual communication" is possible even classically. If Alice and Bob agree that Bob will send a 1 bit by lobbing a tennis ball toward Alice at a certain time, and send a 0 bit by doing nothing, then if Alice detects no tennis ball at the appropriate time, a bit of information was successfully transmitted between them although no physical communication took place. The number of tennis balls per bit can even be made arbitrarily small (but not 0) in variations of this classical protocol. Note that here too the channel must exist even if it isn't used, i.e. it must be possible for a tennis ball to reach Alice, or else she can't conclude anything from not receiving one.

Answer (score 3):

Counterportation is a portmanteau made from two words "counterfactual" and "transport".

You mentioned two related concepts, one of them teleportation. Here's the difference. While counterportation achieves the end goal of teleportation - namely the disembodied transport of a quantum bit (qubit) across space - it does so without teleportation's main prerequisites. These are previously shared entanglement between sender and receiver on the one hand, and classical communication between them on the other.

The upshot is that in counterportation a quantum object is reconstituted across space without any particles crossing.

The fact that counterprotation does not require pre-shared entanglement does not mean that entanglement is not involved. Rather, spatial entanglement between sender and receiver is gradually generated from scratch, before the process is reversed, ending with the quantum object on the other side.

Now, doesn't that bring to mind what a traversable wormhole does? - namely allowing space to be traversed in the absence of any observable journey in the ambient space.

It's a traversable wormhole because it does what a traversable wormhole does: bridge space.

The paper uses the recently developed [constructor theory](https://www.constructortheory.org) of information to give a general yet precise characterization of what is referred to as a local wormhole. The word "local" is a reminder that counterportation takes place at some fraction of the speed of light. So, nothing instantaneous here.

Implementing such a traversable wormhole amounts to building a 2-qubit exchange-free quantum computer - i.e. one where each communicating party has one qubit, and where no particles cross between them.

This is different from the other concept you mentioned - the idea that a computer can give the result of a computation without running - but was inspired by it, among other ideas.

The fact that a quantum object can be reconstituted across space exchange-free could shed light on questions such as the nature of spacetime, and the reality of the quantum state. At least that's the hope.

As for how overhyped or otherwise, I'll let others - and ultimately time - settle that. The paper, which is open-access, can be found here,

https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2058-9565/ac8ecd

And a less technical narrative can be found in this blog-post,

https://physicscommunity.nature.com/posts/traversable-wormhole-in-the-laboratory

Hope this helps.

P.S. The fact that counterportation is described by quantum theory does not exclude a holographic dual description that contains gravity.

Comment: so.. is this a type of quantum teleportation or not? I can't really tell from the paper. "Disembodied transport" doesn't mean much to me; is it a protocol where a state held by one party ends up to another party (as in teleportation), or is it something else?

Comment: Are not you simply send information by NOT sending photons when it is physically possible? If so, it is just sending signal by making a pause. No particle are transferred, information is transferred, but this is not anything special because you need a communiction channel anyway.

Comment: For instance, classically you can agree on the following protocol: there is a communication channel between Alice and Bob. Bob starts a counter which increases every millisecond. When he receives a signal, he considers the number on the counter as received. This way, by waiting appropriate number of millisecondss, Alice can send any number to Bob and do it by using the signal only once. She can send gigabytes of information using just one photon.